# Autocomplete Jquery Ruby on Rails routing error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, routes

I am having a problem with my routing, I still do not understand it fully so I thank you all for your explanations.

the address being called = GET /buyorders/autocomplete?term=i HTTP/1.1

where I want it to look = controller=> buyorders, action=> autocomplete

the location it is looking in = app/controllers/buyorders_controller.rb:26:in **`show'** <<

The route I have placed to make it look at where I want =
match "buyorders/autocomplete?term=* " => "buyorders#autocomplete"

but it is still looking at show action. 
the route that I have placed does exist in rake routes
I have tried restarting server but this has not helped

I have also found another way of making routes in other stack overflow questions such as writing it as 
route.connect "/buyorders/autocomplete?term=*", :controller => "buyorders", :action => "autocomplete" but this crashed routes.rb so im thinking its possibly for older version of ROR? I am using 3.1

I thank you all again for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem was because

resource :buyorder # was before 
match "buyorder/autocomplete" => "buyorder#autocomplete"

by flipping the two around, the problem was solved I guess resource :buyorder was overwriting the match command somehow,

Answer (score 0):

if you're using named parameters (e.g. ?term=something) you don't need to put in the wildcards. You can just do:

```
match 'buyorders/autocomplete' => 'buyorders#autocomplete', :via => :get
```

if you put that in, what does the result of rake routes look like?

Comment: I have changed it to   match "buyorders/autocomplete" => "buyorders#autocomplete", :via => :get, and the output of the rake routes is buyorders_autocomplete get /buyorders/autocomplete(.:format) {:controller => "buyorders", :action => "autocomplete"}, This change didnt fix the problem at this time

Comment: what is the problem? it is reporting the correct controller and the correct action?

Comment: sorry when I said problem I was referencing to my original question, it is still trying to access the show action in buyorders, when I want it to access the autocomplete action in buyorders, as for rake routes, it is reporting the correct controller and action which is why I am lost too =(

Comment: I am not understanding what you're saying. What do you mean by "trying to access show." Where does that happen? Do you have a console output or an error message?

Comment: What I mean is that it is trying to access the show action in the buyorder controller, I know this because I get the output app/controllers/buyorders_controller.rb:26:in `show', I get this from developer tools from chrome,

Comment: Can you put up the form you're using? I think that is where your problem is.

Comment: thank you for all your help and time earnold =), the problem has been fixed I will put up the answer in a bit

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. I fixed it by adding autocomplete path in my routes.rb file

For your example:

```
resources :buyorders do
   get 'autocomplete'
end
```

Comment: I have fixed the issue AyJay it was because the resource :buyorders was before my match, therefore it must have been overwriting it somehow, Then your solution looks like its making autocomplete be considered inside buyorder so I wanted to try it too and added this
  resources :buyorders do
    get "autocomplete" => "buyorders#autocomplete"
  end
however this was still pointing at the show action